# Error deploying Node.J application on AWS Elastic Beanstack

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install my Node.JS Application on AWS Elastic Beanstack. I get the following error. How do I resolve the same.

Regards,
Partha

My application uses JDBC. My machine had Java 0.9.1. However, JDBC would not install. So, I installed Java-1.8 on my machine and set the JAVA_HOME to Java-1.8. On my local machine when I give java -version. I get the following output.

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I am not sure whether the error is due to the wrong version of Java being used while deploying on AWS.

```
Application deployment failed at 2018-10-13T01:36:50Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed.

+ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install

> java@0.9.1 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/java
> node-gyp rebuild

[node-java] Error: not found: javac
gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.11.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.67-66.56.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.11.4-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.11.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.9.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.9.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Could it be that you installed only the Java JRE, and not the JDK?  The Java compiler (javac) is only distirbuted with the JDK...

Comment: In my machine, I have set JAVA-HOME to point to Java 1.8 as I have both Java 0.9.1 and Java 1.8 on my machine. With Java 0.9.1, which was the default as it is the latest version, JDBC package would not install.

apples-imac:pConfMan parthamajumdar$ echo $PATH
/Users/parthamajumdar/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
And

apples-imac:pConfMan parthamajumdar$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home